# difference between "long" and "long int", abs & labs

Tags: c++, types, int, long-integer

This is probably just an inconsistency of notation at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/labs/), but is there a difference between "long int" and "long" types in C++?  cplusplus.com says that abs takes inputs of types "int" and "long", whereas labs uses "long int".  I assume that this is basically a typo.  If so, then is the only difference between abs and labs that labs is guaranteed to return a long?

Comment: In the early development of C, it seems that people liked leaving out `int` wherever they could, probably to cut down on typing.  (Terminals then were very little like terminals now.  Ever typed on a Teletype?)  This meant that `long int` and `short int` were typically shortened to `long` and `short`.

Comment: @jpalecek:  At least we got rid of the implicit `int` when there was absolutely nothing left.  I still do get warnings about implicit `int` in VC++ 2008 when I've confused the compiler, so people still remember it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference between `long` and `long int`.

The reason we have `abs(long)` and `labs(long)` (while both are equivalent) is that `labs()` is a remnant of the C library. C doesn't have function overloading, so function `abs()` can only take one type (`int`) and the `long` one has to be called differently, hence `labs`.

Comment: @jpalecek any reference to the standard?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.  Similar to "unsigned" and "unsigned int".  Yes, in C++ there's an overload for abs() that takes a long argument.  labs() is necessary for C programmers, they can only use the abs() function that takes an int.  The C language doesn't support function overloading.

Answer (score 1):

`long int` is the same type as `long`. `abs` and `labs` are from C where there is no function overloading. `long abs(long)` is the same as `long labs(long)` in C++. For example, GCC has

```
inline long abs(long __i) { return labs(__i); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`long` and `long int` are equivalent and interchangeable.